# How to get client's IP in a golang thrift server

Tags: go, thrift

I'm writing a thrift service in golang and I would like to understand how I can get the client's IP address in the handler functions context.

Thanks, Love.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using this [Godoc Thrift library](http://godoc.org/git.apache.org/thrift.git/lib/go/thrift). It would be good to have code snippets in your question; such as type of `thrift server`, `handler` definition, etc.

As per Thrift Go [library doc](http://godoc.org/git.apache.org/thrift.git/lib/go/thrift#TSocket.Addr)-

> func (p *TSocket) Addr() net.Addr
>
> Returns the remote address of the socket.

So if you have access to `TSocket` then you can get remote address.